# Spring FactoryBean that depend on type parameters

Tags: java, spring, generics, factory

I have a generic Java interface, let's call it Repository (not related to Spring Data), and want to inject Repository<T> into my components. I want to create a type of factory in the Spring container that can generate instances of Repository *but*, that needs to known which type argument was used to do so.

I imagine that Spring Data must be doing something similar, as I can request a repository of a specific type, but I do not know how to register a factory in Spring that is aware of the parameterized type of the object that it's creating.

Is there another Spring concept that I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: Regarding what you said "I imagine that Spring Data must be doing something similar, as I can request a repository of a specific type", could you explain how exactly you do that? How do you request such a repository? Thanks

Comment: If you are using spring 4 this should just work. https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics

Comment: @SeanCarroll, that post shows how Spring can inject components based on genetic type parameters, but you still need to configure each type parameter explicitly. I want a single factory to create instances for all possible type arguments, but based on the type argument actually used, passed as a Class instance to the factory at runtime.

Comment: Yes it would be explicit however whats the value in the ability to create instances for all type argument? What is your use case?. What good would be Repository<Long> or Repository<String> be in your scenario? What repositories would you be creating in those instances?

Comment: In my setup, I would need access to the type argument to know how to deserialise values of the type, think different classes serialised as JSON rather than just primitives. All other logic would be identical.

Comment: Thats exactly my point. You know what classes you need repositories for...this is how Spring Data works. In Spring Data you still need to create interfaces for your repositories: eg interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Long>. These can be picked up via component scanning, registered as beans and allow you to inject based on the generic parameter. If you have more code that you can provide perhaps that will be helpful to see what you have and what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: It may not be possible in spring but that doesn't make it less useful. I simply want to avoid the overhead of having to create those explicit interfaces since they add no value other than maybe to assist Spring. My service using the interface will only use methods from Repository, and my configuration can be done once for all of them - why should I need to create more interfaces?

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm looking for the exact same thing